# AWT- In what order are update() and paint() methods called?

Tags: java, applet, awt

I'm reading Herbert Schildt's Java 2 5e. In the chapter on Applets, he says,

> The default version of update() first fills an applet with the default background color and then calls paint().

So I experience flashing when the applet starts(or is resized) with this code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class awt_ extends Applet{
public void init() {
}

public void start() {
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setForeground(Color.white);
    g.drawString("this", 20, 20);
}

public void stop() {}
public void destroy() {}
}
```

So far, so good. The book and [this page](http://hepunx.rl.ac.uk/~adye/javatutorial/ui/drawing/update.html) suggest overriding `update()` and moving the painting code into `update()`. The website also mentions that,

> An easy way to implement paint() is to simply have it call update()

So i modified my code to the following with the expectation that flashing would not occur, but it still does! Here's the modified code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class awt_ extends Applet{
public void init() {
}   

public void start() {
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    update(g);
}

public void update(Graphics g) {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setForeground(Color.white);
    g.drawString("this", 20, 20);
}
public void stop() {}
public void destroy() {}
```

}

1)As per the book, `update()` is called before `paint()`. So, my overridden `update()` *should not* clear the background before calling `paint()`. But, this doesn't happen from the flashing still observed.

2)If the default implementation of `update()` calls `paint()`, then with the latter method, why should `paint()` call `update()`?

3)What's the order in which these functions are called and when?

What am I missing here?

Comment: See [Painting in Awt and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#db) for more detail. Why are you learning AWT. I would spend my time learning Swing. You can still create Swing applets. See the [Swing Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more up to date examples. That book and code is 10 years old.

Comment: Unfortunately our instructor uses AWT. Although I am somewhat comfortable with basics of Java, I'm pretty new to AWT,Swing,Applets and whatnot. And I've a project to submit within 25 days:(